Irrationality of angles of odd Gaussian primes
Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$ be a prime number such that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and let $a+ib=\sqrt{p}e^{2\pi i \theta}$ be a Gaussian prime such that
$$
p=a^2+b^2.
$$
Question: How do we show that $\theta$ cannot be a rational number?
Note that for $p=2=1^2+1^2$ we have $a+ib=1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i \pi /4  }$, so $\theta=1/8\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Thus, the assumption $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ is important.

Thanks for the link! I've been reading the paper of Cilleruelo and Cordoba, see here: link. On page 902, line 11, they claim that angles corresponding to distinct Gauss integers and 1 are linearly independent over the rationals. It implies that each of these angles is irrational.

If $\theta$ is rational, then $(a+bi)^k$ must be real, for some $k.$ Use unique factorization in Gaussian integers.

@ThomasAndrews I thought about it, but I'm confused about the details. Should we argue that one cannot have $(a+ib)^k=(a-ib)^k$ due to uniqueness of Gaussian prime factorization? How is that different from the case $a=b=1$ for which $(1+i)^4=(1-i)^4$?  Thank you for your response!

$a+bi$ cannot be a factor of $a-bi$ or visa versa, except when $a+bi=\pm1\pm i$ You have to show this, of course.

If $a+bi\mid a-bi$ then $a+bi\mid 2a$ and $2b.$  Since $a+bi$ is prime, we can't have a common factor $a,b,$ unless  one of them is zero.

Ok, I see. Thanks a lot for your help!

Let $p\in\Bbb{Z}$ be a prime number such that $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$. Then there exist $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $p=a^2+b^2$, and $a+bi\in\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is prime. Clearly $a$ and $b$ are nonzero and coprime.
Write $a+bi=\sqrt{p}e^{2\pi i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\Bbb{R}$. Suppose $\theta=\tfrac{c}{d}$ where $c$ and $d$ are coprime positive integers. Then
$$(a+bi)^{2d}=\left(\sqrt{p}e^{2\pi i c/d}\right)^{2d}=p^de^{4\pi ic}=p^d=(a^2+b^2)^d=(a+bi)^d(a-bi)^d.$$
Because $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ are both prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, by unique factorization of Gaussian integers we find that $a-bi=u(a+bi)$ for some unit $u\in\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Of course $u=i^k$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, and we see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
i&=&0\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad a-bi=a+bi\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad b=0,\\
i&=&1\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad a-bi=-b+ai\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad a=-b,\\
i&=&2\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad a-bi=-a-bi\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad a=0,\\
i&=&3\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad a-bi=b-ai\qquad&\Rightarrow&\qquad a=b.\\
\end{eqnarray*}
We already noted that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero and coprime, so $i=0$ and $i=2$ are impossible, and $i=1$ and $i=3$ imply that $|a|=|b|=1$. But then $p=a^2+b^2=2$, contradicting our assumption that $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$. We conclude that no such integers $c$ and $d$ exist, i.e. that $\theta$ is not rational.
